# SP 2013 workflow CompositeTask CompletionCriteria

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, visual-studio-2013

Designing a declarative workflow with Visual Studio 2013 I try to use a CompositeTask to fulfill the following requirements

- approval workflow for multiple users with a parallel task
- if at least 50% of the users respond we go on with the workflow
- the outcome of the CompositeTask is 'rejected' if only one of the responses is 'rejected'

So I set the CompletionCriteria of the CompositeTask activity

- 'Wait for percentage of a response'
- CompletionCriteriaProperties: 'Percentage' = 50; 'InterestedOutcome' = 3

[according to MSDN dev network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.activities.compositetask.completioncriteria(v=office.15).aspx)

The thing with the 50% works. Good, but the task outcome is **always approved**. So at the moment the 50% response criteria is what the task makes to say 'success'. But how to tell it that it has to consider the 'specific outcome' of the several responses?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Required outcome to "Approved" and the Default outcome to "Rejected". The note below the Completion criteria says: "This option will make the workflow wait until a specified percentage of a particular outcome is received. *If the required percentage is not achieved, it will return the default outcome.*"

Comment: but as you say: "until a specified percentage of a particular outcome is received", but our condition is "if at least 50% of the users respond" - so a particular outcome isn't considered!

Comment: okey, this aspect I missed. Sorry.